# Is there a way fetch javascript data with axios or do the data need to be only in json format to do so?

Tags: javascript, arrays, axios

I would like to know if I can fetch javascript data with axios or is the only way is to them and using the map method to do so?

```
const [englishData, setEnglishData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const ENGLISHDICO = await axios.get('./src/shared/english-phobia.js');
    setEnglishData(ENGLISHDICO);
    console.log(ENGLISHDICO);
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

The javascript data look like this:

```
export const ENGLISHDICO = {
x: [
    {
      id: 303,
      rating: 5,
      phobiaName: 'xanthophobia',
      description: 'fear of the color yellow',
    },
    {
      id: 304,
      rating: 5,
      phobiaName: 'xenophobia',
      description: 'fear of strangers',
    },
    {
      id: 305,
      rating: 5,
      phobiaName: 'xerophobia',
      description: 'fear of dryness',
    },
    {
      id: 306,
      rating: 5,
      phobiaName: 'xylophobia',
      description: 'fear of forests',
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: What does this "*javascript data*" look like, exactly? Can you edit your question to include a sample of this data?

Comment: Axios can fetch any kind of data.

Comment: But why are you using destructuring with the result? If it's JavaScript, then it's not JSON that will be parsed into an object. Axios won't *execute* the script, it just returns the source code.

Comment: @Barma glad to know thx!